# Bootstrap responsive content font size

Tags: php, css, responsive

I have simple php code with loops who gets code from API and result displays on monitor. Porblem starts when there is many 'objects' to show, they goes out of monitor (i don't need scrollbar etc., because it's on whall without keyboard/mouse).
How I can make responsive content who resizes by content quantity and fixed display sizes? I use Bootstrap 3.
My "BODY" code:

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">API TEST</h1>
     <div class='d-inline-block p-2 btn-danger rounded'>.$value['Caption'].</div>
     <div class='d-inline-block p-2 btn-success rounded'>.$value['Caption'].</div>
     <div class='d-inline-block p-2 btn-info rounded'>.$value['Caption'].</div>
  </div>
</main>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.05;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.my-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
}
.btn-success {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
}
.btn-success:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
}
.btn-danger {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #ff132a;
  border-color: #ff132a;
}
.btn-danger:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #ff132a;
  border-color: #ff132a;
}
.btn-info {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
}
.btn-info:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.4rem !important;
  margin: 0.4rem !important;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.alertAudio {
  visibility: hidden !important;
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:-50px; 
  left:0; 
  width:160px; 
  height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML, not the PHP. This is an HTML/CSS issue and not related to your PHP.

Comment: This is all index code. There is only div's into php code. It's all.

Comment: Yeah, post the rendered HTML. What you have in the question doesn't help us, since we have no idea how the final markup looks. View source on your page and copy what the PHP outputs and add that to the question.

Comment: Why did you rollback? Your edit is what we need to see.

Comment: theoretically you could count the characters of the output and choose the font size based on the number of the characters. But this is only a very superficial answer because I have not seen the application.

Comment: Sorry, only learning all the things. :)

Max - that solution been on old code, but before I make it again - want to know, is there html/css option to make page responsive by content quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Get job done with jQuery and TextFill. Work great for my needs.

[More info about TextFill](http://jquery-textfill.github.io/)